# How can I add docstrings to android maven-publish .aar files in build.gradle.kts?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, maven-publish

I have a project with the standard java library and this creates several `.jar` files, one being a docset and another the source set. Now I have successfully created an android-library using the [maven-publish](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin) plugin, but when I add the `.aar` files to another project, they don't contain neither source nor comments as the `.jar` version did, so I don't get help inside the IDE or look into the implementation of methods.

What do I need to add to my `build.gradle.kts` to include docstrings and sources in the debug version of the `.aar` I'm publishing locally as a file? The linked gradle documentation from that Android developer page does not mention anything about docstrings or sources at all.

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.KotlinCompilerVersion

plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    kotlin("android")
    `maven-publish`
}

group = "com.wavelt.libs"
version = "1.0.0"


android {
    compileSdkVersion(30)
    buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(16)
        targetSdkVersion(30)
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xinline-classes")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk7", KotlinCompilerVersion.VERSION))
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0")
    androidTestImplementation("com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2")
    androidTestImplementation("com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2")
}

// https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin
afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        repositories {
            maven {
                // https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:repositories
                url = uri("$buildDir/repository")
            }
        }
        publications {
            create<MavenPublication>("debug") {
                // Applies the component for the release build variant.
                from(components["debug"])
                artifactId = "wavelt-android-debug"
                artifact("androidJavadocsJar") // Doesn't seem to work
            }
            create<MavenPublication>("release") {
                // Applies the component for the release build variant.
                from(components["release"])
                artifactId = "wavelt-android"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I've read about other devs being able to cram the javadocs into the `.aar` file, this is not explicitly necessary at all to gain documentation and source code inspection from inside IDEs like Android Studio. In fact, looking at the way a typical java library works, it creates files like:

- `foo-ver.jar`
- `foo-ver-sources.jar`
- `foo-ver-javadoc.jar`

The only difference with an Android library would be having these files:

- `foo-ver.aar`
- `foo-ver-sources.jar`
- `foo-ver-javadoc.jar`

Which means that the sources and javadoc jars can still be copied along the `.aar` and the IDE will load them. Having said that, the publish example code only creates the `.aar` file, looking at [other questions like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65934402/maven-publication-with-documentation) I was able to modify the script to create the `.aar` plus the two other `.jar` packages:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.KotlinCompilerVersion

plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    kotlin("android")
    `maven-publish`
    id("org.jetbrains.dokka") version "0.9.17"
}

group = "com.wavelt.libs"
version = "1.0.0"


android {
    compileSdkVersion(30)
    buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(16)
        targetSdkVersion(30)
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xinline-classes")
    }
}

dependencies {
    //implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar"))))
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk7", KotlinCompilerVersion.VERSION))
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0")
    androidTestImplementation("com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2")
    androidTestImplementation("com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2")
}

tasks.dokka {
    outputFormat = "html"
    outputDirectory = "$buildDir/javadoc"
    moduleName = rootProject.name
}

val dokkaJar by tasks.creating(Jar::class) {
    group = JavaBasePlugin.DOCUMENTATION_GROUP
    description = "Assembles Kotlin docs with Dokka"
    archiveClassifier.set("javadoc")
    from(tasks.dokka)
    dependsOn(tasks.dokka)
}

val sourcesJar by tasks.creating(Jar::class) {
    group = JavaBasePlugin.DOCUMENTATION_GROUP
    description = "Assembles sources JAR"
    archiveClassifier.set("sources")
    from(android.sourceSets.getByName("main").java.srcDirs)
}

artifacts {
    archives(sourcesJar)
    archives(dokkaJar)
}

// https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin
afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        repositories {
            maven {
                // https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:repositories
                url = uri("$buildDir/repository")
            }
        }
        publications {
            create<MavenPublication>("debug") {
                // Applies the component for the release build variant.
                from(components["debug"])
                artifactId = "wavelt-android-debug"
                artifact(sourcesJar)
                artifact(dokkaJar)
            }
            create<MavenPublication>("release") {
                // Applies the component for the release build variant.
                from(components["release"])
                artifactId = "wavelt-android"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With these modifications the `./gradlew publish` task will generate all files, and despite one of them having `.aar` they work the same as `.jar` when copied together into another project.